# KeyError in python dataframe

Tags: python

I tried to merge the winning dataset and the original pokemon dataset

```
    numberOfWins = numberOfWins.sort_index()
    numberOfWins['Total Fights'] = countByFirst.Winner + countBySecond.Winner

    numberOfWins['Win Percentage'] = numberOfWins.First_pokemon/numberOfWins['Total Fights']

    results2 = pd.merge(pokemon, numberOfWins, right_index = True, left_on = 'Number')
    results3 = pd.merge(pokemon, numberOfWins, left_on='Number', right_index = True, how='left')
```

ERROR:
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_label_or_level_values(self, key, axis)
   1772             values = self.axes[axis].get_level_values(key)._values
   1773         else:
-> 1774             raise KeyError(key)
   1775 
   1776         # Check for duplicates

KeyError: 'Number'

Answer (score 0):

First remove duplicat keys from right table by ->  df[['Number']].drop_duplicates()

check the spelling for the keys on both the tables and mention it in the below merge 
Then use pd.merge(pokemon, numberOfWins, how='left', left_on= 'Number', right_on='Number')

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
numberOfWins = numberOfWins.sort_index()
numberOfWins['Total Fights'] = countByFirst.Winner + countBySecond.Winner

numberOfWins['Win Percentage'] = numberOfWins.First_pokemon/numberOfWins['Total Fights']

results2 = pd.merge(pokemon, numberOfWins, right_index = True, left_on = 'Number', right_on = 'Number')
results3 = pd.merge(pokemon, numberOfWins, left_on='Number', right_on = 'Number' right_index = True, how='left')
```

Make sure both dataframes has a column named `Number` in them, which has the same type and obviously, should also have values that exist in both.